# Free for all mode, allow team killing

Tags: counter-strike-source, sourcemod

I'm trying to set up a CS:S server with Gun Game and Deathmatch.  I have everything done except I want it to be a free-for-all style, where you can kill your own team mate and be awarded points.

I have installed this plugin to that points are awarded: https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=156587

And have set these cvars:

```
// Allow friendly fire
mp_friendlyfire 1
// Don't kick users for friendly fire
mp_autokick 0
// Enable freeforall plugin
sm_freeforall 1
```

What I'm stuck on is a message saying

> Careful!
>   Killing teammates will not be tolerated!"

Is still showing up.  I'm also not sure that damage being dealt to teammates is the same as damage dealt to enemies.

Is there something I'm missing to enable this?  I thought it would have been simpler.

Comment: Not sure but you can try and change this message in titles.txt, the key is `"Cstrike_TitlesTXT_Hint_careful_around_teammates"` then change the value to `""` that may work.

Comment: As long as friendlyfire is on 1 damage should be equal to both Enemies and teammates.

Comment: @GEnGEr Yes, I agree. Unlike CS:GO, where friendly fire is reduced based on other CVARs, it is an "all-or-nothing" situation in CS:S. The "Killing enemies will not be tolerated" hint is something that appears on the clientside -- can't clients turn that off? It's been ages since I played CS:S specifically.